# How to tweet / post a Facebook status from Django?

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I would like to have the option for a registered user to tweet/post a FB status from Django app.

I'm using python-social-auth with Facebook/Twitter enabled.

How can I add such functionality to all registered users? (for those who signed up using their FB/Twitter account and for those who didn't)

Thanks

Comment: "and for those who didn't" - you can't (unless you make him go though the FB/twitter oauth process anyway)

Comment: for those i can make them go through the FB/twitter oauth process

Comment: How can i post a status to Fb or tweet once i have both access tokens?

Comment: I guess [this][1] will solve the problem for you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132630/how-do-i-update-facebook-status-from-my-own-website